# Unable to automate mouse over using webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am unable to automate mouse over using webdriver with below code. I would appreciate if anybody gave the solution

```java
Actions builder = new Actions(driver); 
WebElement el=driver.findElement(By.linkText("Account"));
System.out.println(el.getText());
builder.moveToElement(el);
Thread.sleep(5000);
WebElement ele1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[4]/div/ul/li[4]/a"));
System.out.println(ele1.getText());
builder.moveToElement(ele1);
builder.click();
builder.perform();
Thread.sleep(5000L);
```

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/form/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[4]/div‌​/ul/li[4]/a"}

Its not identifying dropdown element .So that the item in the menu is not visible.thats the cause of this error.

Comment: Yes.org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/form/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[4]/div/ul/li[4]/a"}     _Its not identifying dropdown element .So that the item in the menu is not visible.thats the cause of this error.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry i cant post it publicly because of security reasons.Is there any other option to give the control to menu list except "Action".So that i can try with that.

Answer (score 0):

I see you hadn't included the SUT- And I see you have issues with incorrect xpath. You need to fix that. If you're unable to figure out the real xpath. Perhaps you should use Selenium IDE to get the context out of its script.

Once you sort it out. You could try the following to stimulate mouse over.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[4]/div/ul/li[4]/a"));
Locatable hoverItem = (Locatable) element;
Mouse mouse = ((HasInputDevices) driver).getMouse();
mouse.mouseMove(hoverItem.getCoordinates());
```